# How to run a create index script using RoundhousE that depends on a sp in the correct sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-versioning, roundhouse

Question on [roundhouse](http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2009/11/19/roundhouse-version-your-database.aspx). I have a script that calls a sp to figure out how much space is required to create an index. (we are using sql express which has max db size limit). Depending on how much space is left it deletes rows from a whole bunch of tables and then creates the index with the usual checks (if not exists in sysindex...create index...). The sp called will be used in other index creation scripts in the future so unless there is no option I would prefer to keep it as a sp and not part of the create index script (inline). Problem is that roundhouse runs my index creation script in the UP folder first and then goes after the sp folder or runfirstafterUp folder. It cannot find the sp since it has not been plugged into the db first. Pls advise if there is any solution to this sequence problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest RH has an indexes folder that is run after the sprocs folder https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions

Let me know if this solves your issue. Thanks!

UPDATE for Clarity: Newest version doesn't necessarily reflect what is released. The version you use needs to be greater than 324 ( http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/source/detail?r=324 ).

You can install RH in many ways - https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/Getroundhouse

Comment: @fervenrcoder I moved on using the runFirstAfterUp folder since it does not seem to be "Looking for indexes" folder. In the log file I see looking for sprcs, views all the other looking for except Indexes.. Is this a bug ? thanks

Comment: @Gullu - When I said NEWEST version I should have specified that it's not v300 (on the downloads list) because it is not officially released yet. The version you use needs to be greater than 324 ( http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/source/detail?r=324 ).